# Jquery Checkbox Checked Show / Hide Div if two checkboxes is check or unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have this simple jquery code for checkbox that checks via attributes. I know that there are many similarities for this answered already but the idea here is different.

I want to show the `A_B` div element for the following condition:

**#1:** User `checked` checkbox `A` or `B` then shows the `A_B` div element

**#2:** If user `unchecked` `A` checkbox but checkbox `B` is still checked. Then `A_B` div element is still showing.

`*Note: This can be reversal for the situation*`

**#3** If user uncheckeds both `A` or `B` checkbox. Then only `A_B` div element will hide.

Right now. When I uncheck `A` or `B` checkbox. The div element will hide, should not suppose to toggle.
Is there anything here to improve. To achieve the following `3` conditions?

Any ideas / solutions would be a great help. Might be useful also to some users that encounters the same problem as mine. Thanks.

```js
$('input[chck-type="a_b"]').click(function(){
    if (
    $(this).prop("checked") == true
  ) {
      $('.A_B').removeClass('hide');
  } else {
    $('.A_B').addClass('hide');
  }
});

$('input[chck-type="c"]').click(function(){
    if (
    $(this).prop("checked") == true
  ) {
      $('.C_Box').removeClass('hide');
  } else {
    $('.C_Box').addClass('hide');
  }
});
```

```css
.hide {display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><input type="checkbox" chck-type="a_b">A</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" chck-type="a_b">B</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" chck-type="c">C</p>


<div class='A_B hide'>
This box is for A or B.
</div>

<div class='C_Box hide'>
This box is for C.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not checking if both checkboxes are unchecked or not.

```js
$('input[chck-type="a_b"]').click(function(){
    if (
    $(this).prop("checked") == true
  ) {
      $('.A_B').removeClass('hide');
  } else if($('input[chck-type="a_b"]')[0].checked == false && $('input[chck-type="a_b"]')[1].checked == false) {
    $('.A_B').addClass('hide');
  }
});

$('input[chck-type="c"]').click(function(){
    if (
    $(this).prop("checked") == true
  ) {
      $('.C_Box').removeClass('hide');
  } else {
    $('.C_Box').addClass('hide');
  }
});
```

```css
.hide {display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><input type="checkbox" chck-type="a_b">A</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" chck-type="a_b">B</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" chck-type="c">C</p>


<div class='A_B hide'>
This box is for A or B.
</div>

<div class='C_Box hide'>
This box is for C.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('input[chck-type="a_b"]').click(function(){
    let checkboxes = $('input[chck-type="a_b"]:checked').length;
    if (
    checkboxes != 0
  ) {
      $('.A_B').removeClass('hide');
  } else {
    $('.A_B').addClass('hide');
  }
});

$('input[chck-type="c"]').click(function(){
    if (
    $(this).prop("checked") == true
  ) {
      $('.C_Box').removeClass('hide');
  } else {
    $('.C_Box').addClass('hide');
  }
});
```

```css
.hide {display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p><input type="checkbox" chck-type="a_b">A</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" chck-type="a_b">B</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" chck-type="c">C</p>


<div class='A_B hide'>
This box is for A or B.
</div>

<div class='C_Box hide'>
This box is for C.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change your JS to this and will work.

```js
    $('input').on('click', function () {
      var a_b = $('input[chck-type="a_b"]').is(':checked');
      if (!a_b) {
        $('.A_B').addClass('hide');
      } else {
        $('.A_B').removeClass('hide');
      }

      var c = $('input[chck-type="c"]').is(':checked');
      if (!c) {
        $('.C_Box').addClass('hide');
      } else {
        $('.C_Box').removeClass('hide');
      }
    });
```

```css
    .hide {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <p><input type="checkbox" chck-type="a_b" />A</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" chck-type="a_b" />B</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" chck-type="c" />C</p>

    <div class="A_B hide">This box is for A or B.</div>

    <div class="C_Box hide">This box is for C.</div>
```

Example : [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-q96c1w?file=index.html,index.js,style.css)